# Passing imported View in renderNavigationView of DrawerLayoutAndroid

Tags: react-native

Trying to load partial view inside my drawer but instead, I'm getting blank page.
Can anybody guide me with this;

MainScreen.js
..

```
import DrawerContent from "./PartialViews/DrawerContent";
```

...

```
render() {
    return (
      <DrawerLayoutAndroid
        style={mainStyles.applicationView}
        drawerWidth={300}
        drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
        renderNavigationView={() => {
          <DrawerContent onItemClick={this._change.bind(this)} />;
        }}
        ref={_drawer => this.drawer = _drawer}
      >
```

DrawerContent.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { 
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

import drawerStyles from "../Styles/DrawerContentStyles";

export default class DrawerContent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={drawerStyles.container}>
      ...
      </View>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to react-native development and was also struggling with this same issue, this is how I solved it:

```
const Drawer = (mainscreen) => {
  return (
    <View>
      ...
    </View>
  );
}

export default Drawer;
```

then within your MainScreen you can call it and pass in you context

```
  <DrawerLayoutAndroid 
    ref={'DRAWER'}
    drawerWidth={300}
    drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
    renderNavigationView={() => Drawer(this)}
  >
```

Not sure if this is the right approach, but it works.
Hope this helps